# aligning Image Buttons with TextView XML

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

How do i align the arrows to be right above/below the numbers? Does each arrow need to have it's own linear layout? Is there a way to set this without setting a static amount of padding? I would like this to be generic enough to be used and show up properly on different devices...

I'm relatively new to android development - especially the UI portion of it... so any help would be appreciated!

What I See (Above)
[image]

What I Would Like To See (Above)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest another LinearLayout (with orientation:vertical) inside your LinearLayout (with orientation:horizontal).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/number_picker_up_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/up"
            android:background="@drawable/up" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:text="100"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/OffWhite"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/number_picker_down_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/down"
            android:background="@drawable/down" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/number_picker_up_two" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/up"
            android:background="@drawable/up" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:text="100"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/OffWhite"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/number_picker_down_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/down"
            android:background="@drawable/down" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Note that nesting too many layouts inside a layout is discouraged. Reference: 
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html
But having 2 layout hierarchy is totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest two vertical `LinearLayout`s inside of your horizontal `LinearLayout`. Here's one where I do the same thing but I have empty `View`s on each side and one in the middle. You can take those out if you don't want them and obviously change your `id`s, `background`s, and such

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mpImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mpLL"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mpUpBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            style="@style/UpArrow"
            android:onClick="cycleUp"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/mpTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="breakfast"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/black"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mpDownBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="cycleDown"
            style="@style/DownArrow"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/catLL"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/catUpBtn"
            style="@style/UpArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="cycleUp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Beef"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/black" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/catDownBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="cycleDown"
            style="@style/DownArrow" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

You will notice I have also used `weight` and a `0dp` for the `width` of the nested `LinearLayout`s and for the `View` to give them the separation I wanted and to look right on different screen sizes. You can change those depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can have nested layouts.  Be careful not to have too many, however two should be fine.  Here is an example of what I think you are looking for.  The arrows and text should be aligned thanks to RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/number_picker_up_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/up"
            android:src="@drawable/up" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/number_picker_up_one"
            android:text="100"
            android:textColor="@color/OffWhite"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/number_picker_down_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/one"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/down"
            android:src="@drawable/down" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/number_picker_up_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/up"
            android:src="@drawable/up" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/number_picker_up_two"
            android:text="100"
            android:textColor="@color/OffWhite"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/number_picker_down_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/two"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/down"
            android:src="@drawable/down" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```